# Export data from listview to excel vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I export data from listview to excel. With this code below, it exports all the data I want to export. The problem shows when I export to excel next time. Exported data is added to previously created excel.

[image: Excel No. 1]

[image: Excel No.2]

The code I have used is below:

```
 Private Sub btnExcel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExcel.Click
    Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application
    Dim bkWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim shWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    objExcel = New Excel.Application
    bkWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
    shWorkSheet = CType(bkWorkBook.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView3.Columns.Count - 1
        shWorkSheet.Cells(1, i + 1) = Me.ListView3.Columns(i).Text
    Next
    For i = 0 To Me.ListView3.Items.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To Me.ListView3.Items(i).SubItems.Count - 1
            shWorkSheet.Cells(i + 2, j + 1) = Me.ListView3.Items(i).SubItems(j).Text
        Next
        objExcel.Cells.Select()
        objExcel.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit()
        objExcel.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit()
        objExcel.Cells.Range("A1").Select()
    Next
    bkWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\PDF\Naročilo " + TxtPodjetje.Text + " " + DT_DatumNaročila.Text + ".xlsx")
    bkWorkBook.Close()
    objExcel.Quit()
```

If I close created vb.net app after the first export and restart it works properly and I get data as I want.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: 1) Its added with existing file if you want to create new file means add unique values in excel file name like numeric or datetime with seconds. then try.
2) First check the file existing or not  if existing then give new file name.

Comment: It doesn't help. Even if the file is deleted the problem remains the same.

Comment: in the listview clear added items then try

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I had a hidden listview and didn't see the content is still in the listview. Thanks.